# How to disable simplified context menus in Windows 10 Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, context-menu

I'm looking for a way to disable simplified context menus in Start Menu that are missing some actions which are essential for me.

Below I have provided an example from my home PC to clarify what I refer to as a classic and simplified menu. Please don't bother the language - you should distinguish both menus by their shape. If Microsoft gave other name to those menus, please share that info as it may lead me to relevant articles related to registry modifications for the simplified menu.

[Simplified context menu example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HyzW.png)

[Classic context menu example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owNm6.png)

If you would like to have more details or justification for my request: At work, I'm enforced through policy to use Avecto Defendpoint and its 'Run with Elevated Rights' context menu entry instead of regular 'Run as Administrator' or 'Run as...' (other user). I will never be privileged to use any of those latter two. So I have to use this specific context menu entry and it is absent in simplified menu. In case of many settings, cmd, regedit etc., I cannot simply run them from start menu, but I have to locate them in Windows Explorer before running and then I have classic context menu where I can run them with elavated rights. It's simply frustrating, time consuming and pushing me out of my work context.

Regards,

Peter.

Comment: You cannot disable what context menu items appear as a non-Administrator but difficult to answer this question without knowing what that first screenshot says (context menu items are not English)

Comment: Apologies for non-English items. Screenshots were intended to show two kinds of context menu in Windows 10 which are significantly different in their visual representations, so you would be sure what I refer to as 'simplified' and 'classic'. Text should not be a matter here. Just type regedit in start menu and right click on item found - you'll get simplified context menu. Open Windows Explorer and go to C:\Windows, then right click on regedit.exe - you'll get classic context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that noticeable time has passed without any direct solution to the question (team I work in was still looking for answer over this time period), I have decided to post viable alternative that was recently found by colleague from the team.

The alternative has one drawback: you will have additional icon pinned to taskbar for each application that you need to run with elevated rights. So it won't be helpful if you have a lot of such applications or you want to have minimal set of icons on your taskbar.

---

**The alternative:**

To have quick access to classic context menu of some application (for example cmd.exe or taskmgr.exe in my case), you need to pin the application to taskbar and perform `Shift + Right Click` on the taskbar icon every time you need to use classic context menu for that application.

---

In cases of applications that are simply present on taskbar because they are running or for exceptional cases (like Explorer icon*), you won't be able to access classic context menu.

* If you still have Explorer icon that is present on taskbar by default with fresh installation of Windows, try pinning explorer.exe - you will end up with two icons and only the second one that you have pinned manually will give you possibility to access classic context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of what you want may be lost in translation; isn't "Uruchom jako administrator" the way to run an app with elevated rights, in both the first and second screenshots?  What action is essential that is missing?  (Maybe you can point out which option on the detailed context menu you're talking about and we can infer through location.)  There is no other way to get a very detailed context menu from the Start Menu, besides resorting to a third party solution like [OpenShell](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu).

But because you're talking about different rights at work, maybe you're talking about "Run as different user"?  That can be 'unhidden' with a registry tweak.  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` - make a new DWORD named `ShowRunasDifferentUserInStart` and set it to `1`.

Here's what it looks like on mine as a result:
[image: a screenshot of right-clicking a search result on the Start Menu after enabling 'show run as different user in start']

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: "Uruchom jako administrator" is exactly "Run as administrator". When I use it, it fails due to no permissions. I have to use Avecto Defendpoint client which supplies me with "Run with Elevated Rights" context menu option which appears only in 'classic context menu'. So intuitively, I think that I can either completely disable simplified menu or I can enrich it with entry that would call Avecto Defendpoint. I just don't know correct registry path to make such changes.

Comment: So if your current user lacks the permissions to run as administrator, logically you need to run as different user.  (Run as administrator is often referred to as elevated rights, so the confusion with this program making its own entry is understandable.)  Hope that works.  I suspect this new context menu doesn't use the registry at all.

Comment: I appreciate attempt to help, but _please read carefully_. Quoting myself: (1) "I have dedicated application to run apps with 'elevated rights' (probably for company to have detailed tracking of actions performed)." (2) "I have to use Avecto Defendpoint client which supplies me with "Run with Elevated Rights" context menu option which appears only in 'classic context menu'." Expressing the obvious directly: it is a company policy enforcing usage of Avecto Defendpoint and I'm not an admin of that computer. I will never get credentials for any other user to "Run as...".